# Angular Assigning Object to $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating an Angular application in which the form fields fill based on the data return from the MongoDB. In order to do that know I am taking the data that is returned in the object and assigning it individually to the $scope.  Like below.

```
  //Keep fields filled in for current session
  $scope.fill = function(id){
      var cookie = $cookies.get('sessionID');     
      $http.get('/data/cookie/' + cookie).success(function(data) {

      $scope.personal = {name: data[0].name, address: data[0].address, phone: data[0].phone, city: data[0].city, state: data[0].state, zip: data[0].zip, email: data[0].email, marital: data[0].marital, ssn: data[0].ssn, dob: data[0].dob};

      $scope.income = {occupation: data[0].income[0].occupation, salary: data[0].income[0].salary, employer_phone: data[0].income[0].employer_phone, date_employeed: data[0].income[0].date_employeed};

      $scope.updated = '';


   }); 

  }
```

I then display that data in the form field using ng-model like below.

```
<div ng-init="fill()" class="rightsec">
<div><p>Occupation</p><input class="long" type="text" ng-model="income.occupation" placeholder="Occupation"/></div>
<div><p>Salary</p><input class="medium" ng-model="income.salary" type="text" placeholder="Salary"/></div>
<div><p>Employer Phone</p><input class="medium" ng-model="income.employer_phone" type="text" placeholder="Employer Phone"/></div>
<div><p>Date Employed</p><input class="medium" type="text" ng-model="income.date_employeed" placeholder="Date Employed"/></div>
</div>
```

Everything works as expected but I'm wondering if there is a better way to assign the data to the scope? I have several more fields and I think this is bad practice.

Comment: Can I have an idea how is the structure of your response data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the structure of my data I was able to simplify and just do this.

```
      $scope.personal = data[0];

      $scope.income = data[0].income[0];
```